# Split the string array

Tags: arrays, json, string, web-services, http

I know this question was absolutely answered but i did not find solution.
I get response from web-service a Json string response that is ["11,22222","33,44444"].

I try this but did not work because string include these characters [ ] and first comma is in the here 11,22

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

URL url2 = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
rd.close();
String res = new String(result);      
String [] coordinates = res.split(",");
```

How can i separate this string like "11,22222"  and "33,44444"

Comment: You can convert this to JsonObject and then it will work like array. Other workaround is res.split("\""); Now you will get your values in 1 and 3 index.

Comment: What's language? C#? Java?

Comment: Java i  can handle with @maddy23285 solution as  res.split("\"");

Answer (score 0):

Just use JavaScriptSerializer.

```
    public void Method(string json)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    List<string> results = js.Deserialize<List<string>>(json); 
}
```

Comment: I'm working on Eclipse with Java how can i use JavaScriptSerializer

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer is part of the System.Web.Extensions.dll. I use this in c#. Not 100% sure if it's also available in Java. Been years since I did actual Java.
After looking some stuff up, there's apparently Gson for Java

Comment: My bad, JavaScriptSerializer is a C# dll. Not usable for Java. But there is flexjson, gson, json-io, ...

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonArray jArray=new JsonArray(result);
StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer();
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
{
s.append(jArray.getString(i));
Log.e(“singleValue”,jArray.getString(i));
}
Log.e(“responsed”,s.toString());
```

Comment: JsonArray not library on eclipse i think so i can not import it

Comment: While the code snippet may solve the question, it is better to include reasons of issue, proposed solution and provide the code as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting a json, you can easily convert it to JsonArray and iterate thorugh it.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonArray array = gson.fromJson(rd, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonArray();
for (JsonElement jsonElement : array) {
System.out.println(jsonElement.getAsString());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If bufferedReader doesn't work, pass the string in the fromJson method.

`JsonArray array = gson.fromJson(res, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonArray();`

Comment: Thanx for help men, but i work on eclipse with Java so should i add package or jar for Gson library or JsonArray

Comment: If you are using maven, add gson dependency, otherwise add it to build path jars.